# CSS - perform transition when hover over li element (dropdown menu)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, transition

I'm making a homepage like this: http://jsbin.com/umaguc/1/ and I'm currently working on the dropdown menu. Now what I want is to make an effect like: http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/249/index.html; I have a div `id="lavalamp"` which has width, height and background color (looks like a rectangle); when I **hover** one of `#nav ul li` element (like Home, Game Offline, Game Online, Esport, Music ...) i want this `#lavalamp` div to be moved and changed its width so that it will looks like the effect I mentioned above.
This is the idea for my code:

```
#nav li:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ #lavalamp {
    left: 39px;
}

#nav li:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ #lavalamp {
    left:110px;
    width:110px;
}
```

but sadly it's just not work. When I hover over an `#nav ul li` element, nothing changes ! Hope you guys can have me with this problem .. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you post the html you are using?

Comment: Sorry ^^ I've just updated the html & css I'm using in the jsbin link.

Comment: Check on http://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-css3-lavalamp-menu/, like raddevon said it looks like your lavalamp div isn't where it should be.

Comment: Ok, i fixed it and everything works nicely. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've used a [general sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) to select `#lavalamp`, but that element never appears as a sibling of your `li` element.

Unfortunately, I don't believe CSS has a way for you to climb back up the DOM to get to your `#lavalamp` from the `li`s. You could use jQuery, or you could think about ways to restructure your markup that would make the element accessible through pure CSS.